# how to redirect page to last incremented id after submitting form

Tags: php, mysql

here is my code 
            }

```
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully Register!');</script>";
        echo "<script>document.location='detail.php?id=$id'</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Assign this to `$id` and your script should work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

got the solution

```
enter code here
```

"header('Location: details.php?id=' . mysqli_insert_id($con)"